# Hooke's law and air resistance - differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I am trying to solve this problem: 
The force acting on a moving object is proportional to its displacement. In the same time, the object experiences the force of air resistance proportional to its speed. Find displacement as a function of time.

My problem is that I have never solved differential equations - I am doing some leisurely reading about Physics and this problem is giving me a hard time.

$$m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b \frac{dx}{dt} + kx = 0$$
This is the equation I am trying to solve. Now, if we neglected the middle term, I know that the auxiliary function $x(t) = Ce^{at}$ could be used, but what can be done in this scenario?

Comment: If the middle term is 0, and if m, k are both positive, you will get $x(t) = C_1 \cos at + C_2\sin at$

Comment: @DougM The middle term is not $0$, because that would mean that there is no air resistance.

Comment: @Botond I am aware of that, I was pointing out a misconception expressed in the original post.

Comment: @DougM I think he knows that - he told that he knows the aauxiliary function in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to substitute $\exp(\lambda t)$ as well. The difference is that $\lambda$ will have a complex and a real part this time. (The real part will cause the loss of velocity).

So let's rename the variables as I've mentioned in the comments to get
$$\ddot x + 2\beta \dot x +\omega_0^2x=0$$
Now substitute $x=\exp(i \omega t)$ (you can use $\lambda$ instead of $i \omega$, it just depends on you), and simplify with the $\exp$ terms:
$$(i \omega)^2 + 2i \beta \omega + \omega_0^2 = 0$$
$$-\omega^2 + 2i \beta \omega + \omega_0^2 = 0$$
$$\omega^2 - 2i \beta \omega - \omega_0^2 = 0$$
Now use the quadratic formula:
$$\omega=\frac{2i\beta \pm \sqrt{-4\beta^2+4\omega_0^2}}{2}$$
$$\omega=i\beta \pm \sqrt{\omega_0^2-\beta^2}$$
Now we need to separate the solution based on the value of $\omega_0^2-\beta^2$. First, let's assume that it's positive. Then we can call it $\Omega^2=\omega_0^2-\beta^2$, so we have that
$$\omega=i\beta \pm \Omega$$
and the solution is in the form
$$x(t)=C_1e^{i(i\beta+\Omega )t}+C_2e^{i(i\beta-\Omega )t}$$
$$x(t)=C_1e^{(-\beta+i\Omega )t}+C_2e^{-(\beta+i\Omega )t}$$
And you can make it a bit nicer with Euler's identity.
If $\omega_0^2-\beta^2$ is negative, then we can call it $\omega_0^2-\beta^2=-\Omega^2$, so we have that
$$\omega=i\beta\pm i\Omega$$
And the solution is
$$x(t)=C_1e^{i(i\beta+i\Omega )t}+C_2e^{i(i\beta-i\Omega )t}$$
$$x(t)=C_1e^{-(\beta+\Omega)t}+C_2e^{-(\beta-\Omega )t}$$
In the third case, $\omega_0^2-\beta^2=0$. Then 
$$\omega=i\beta$$
So the solution is in the form
$$x(t)=C_1e^{i(i\beta)t}+C_2te^{i(i\beta)t}$$ 
$$x(t)=C_1e^{-\beta t}+C_2te^{-\beta t}$$

Comment: Then I get this:
$\lambda^2 + \frac b m \lambda + \frac k m = 0$ Should I now solve for $ \lambda $ ?

Comment: Yes! In the case of $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$, the 2 base will be $\exp(\lambda x)$ and $x \exp(\lambda x)$.

Comment: @Aemilius And if I remember right, we used to call $2\beta = \frac{b}{m}$ and $\omega_0^2 =\frac{k}{m}$. But this is just notation, you don't need to use it.

Comment: @Aemilius could you do it? And don't forget to take the linear combination of the 2 solution - so $C_1\exp(\lambda_1 t)+ C_2 \exp(\lambda_2 t)$.

Comment: One more question - if I get something fancy radical expression as my lambda, how can I know if this number is real or complex? Let's say I get something like this: $\lambda = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 -  4km}}{2m}$ I don't know if it is imaginary or not, should I use Euler anyway?

Comment: @Aemilius I'm going to add it to my answer soon, because it's a bit longer.

Comment: @Aemilius Do you remember when you were introduced to the quadratic equation, the part under the square root sign was called the "determinant"? That's because whether it's positive or negative *determines* whether the solution is real or complex. A system with determinant = 0 is called "critically damped". With determinant > 0, it's "overdamped".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio

Comment: @Aemilius I think my answer is good now.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the differential operator as a variable:

(mD$^2$+bD+k)x=0

This may seem like an abuse of notation, but it works.

If you treat what's in the parentheses as a quadratic polynomial in D, and apply the quadratic formula to find roots $r_1$ and $r_2$, then you have $(D-r_1)(D-r_2)x=0$. You can then take x = $c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ where $(D-r_1)x_1=0$ and $(D-r_2)x_2=0$, or $\frac{dx_1}{dt}-r_1x_1=0$ and $\frac{dx_2}{dt}-r_2x_2=0$. Now you have separable first order differential equations.

Comment: It looks similar to one of my teachers' :D He is rewriting the equation as $L(D)x=0$, where $L(D)=D^2+2\beta D+\omega_0^2$, and he is looking for its eigenvalues.